# Register a child component inside another child component vue.js

Tags: vue.js, components

Imagine I have a parent component say `App.vue` and two other components named `Home.vue` and `Table.vue`. Now I render `Home.vue` inside `App.vue` via `vue-router`. i.e `Home.vue` rendered by using `<router-view></router-view>`. 
Now I want to register and add `Table.vue` inside `Home.vue`. 

N:B: I am just starting vue.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import `Table.vue` to  `Home.vue` like this

```
<template>
 <div>
  ...
  <app-table></app-table>
  ...
 </div>
</template>

<script>
 import Table from 'path/to/Table.vue'
 export default {
  components: {
           appTable : Table
      }
 }
</script
```